# Get list of reports from SSRS?

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services

I've just started working with SSRS and so far I've been able to show reports in my Winforms app using the ReportViewer, by hard-coding the report path.  I would like get a list of reports from SSRS so I can display them and let the user select which one they want to see.

Is there a way to request the list of reports from SSRS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - Report Services has two well established web service interfaces.

Check out this page here: [Report Server Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) and the links off it for more info, or see the [Reporting Services Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522713.aspx) for some background and conceptual info.

Here's the definition of the [ReportingService2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.aspx) class in all its details, specifically there's a [`ListChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.listchildren.aspx) web call which enumerates all items in a given report folder. That will return all reports (and possibly data sources)

Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 3):

use ReportServer
go

select Path, Name from catalog
where type not in (1,5)
order by path, Name

Comment: Nice! Still seems to work in 2024. Any docs for that [catalog] table and the meanings of values in the the [type] field?