# how to set Reportviewer controls report server Url and report path properties in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I m trying to use ReportViewer control in VS2013 to display a report from a SSRS server. The full path to the report URL is like below and I can access report by typing the path in browser

```
http://vm-xx-xxxx/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fname+xxx+And+xxx%2fWorkOrder+UAT
```

I have tried various combinations to set the ReportServerUrl and ReportPath properties but nothing seems to work.

e.g. `ReportPath="/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fxxx+xxx+And+xxx%2fWorkOrder+UAT` and the `ReportServerUrl="http://vm-xx-xxxxx"`

Any ideas how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
ReportServerUrl="http://vm-xx-xxxxx/reportserver"
ReportPath="/xxx+xxx+And+xxx/WorkOrder+UAT"
```

[Configuring ReportViewer for Remote Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075.aspx)

Comment: Any ideas how can we possibly see list of all the reports in a particular folder on the server?

Comment: @Learner: You can either navigate to the folder in a web browser, or [use the web service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1810678/124386).