# Embedding SSRS in my webpage

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to use existing SSRS report in my web page (ASP.net)

I am using ReportViewer in my page and setup Server Report and Report Path

yet the report does not show and getting this error

***The path of the item '/TEST/Financial/WIP+Account' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)***

I looked at this

[how to set Reportviewer controls report server Url and report path properties in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172721/how-to-set-reportviewer-controls-report-server-url-and-report-path-properties-in)

but still not working

here is my code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="DeployRep.Main" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <div>

    </div>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="1239px" ProcessingMode="Remote" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
            <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://mySSRSServ/reportserver" ReportPath="/TEST/Financial/WIP+Account"/>

        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

The reason I get the error was because of the + sign between the words 
I replaced it with space then it worked

```
        <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://mySSRSServ/reportserver" ReportPath="/TEST/Financial/WIP Account"/>
```